# Not Popping up Permission box while clicking on Button- Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

When I run the app, At the runtime it is not asking for the permission but after clicking on the back button, the popup message comes for the permission. I am not able to find out the mistake.

```
public void onClickSignUp(View view){
    String permission = Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS;
    int grant = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);

    Intent intent = new Intent(FirstTimeUserPage.this,SignUpActivity.class);
    if ( grant != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        String[] permission_list = new String[1];
        permission_list[0] = permission;
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permission_list, 1);
    }
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all be careful that you declare these permission in the manifest too .If it don't work .you can use easy permission library that make it easy to request permissions.

Easy permission implementation:

```
implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:3.0.0'
```

after that you implement the library use this code at the runtime in your MainActivity.

```
String[] perms = {Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS};
    if (!EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, perms)) {
        EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, "We need this permission",
                123, perms);
    }
```

For handling that if the permission was granted or not implement this in your activity like the code below:

```
public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks
```

After you implement the code at the top 3 methods come for you that you can handle the situation in your way.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults, this);
}

@Override
public void onPermissionsGranted(int requestCode, @NonNull List<String> perms) {
}

@Override
public void onPermissionsDenied(int requestCode, @NonNull List<String> perms) {
    if (EasyPermissions.somePermissionPermanentlyDenied(this, perms)) {
        new AppSettingsDialog.Builder(this).build().show();
    }
}
```